# How to find products within the cateogry containing the most expensive product

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm currently using the following code:

```
SELECT PROD_NO,
       PROD_NAME,
       PROD_TYPE
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE PROD_SELL IN (SELECT MAX(PROD_SELL)
                    FROM PRODUCTS)
```

Current output:

```
PROD_NO PROD_NAME                      PROD_TYPE           
---------- ------------------------------ --------------------
     40103 StarDome                       Tents
```

Desired Output:

```
 PROD_NO PROD_NAME                      PROD_TYPE           
---------- ------------------------------ --------------------
     40100 Star Lite                      Tents               
     40101 Star Gazer-2                   Tents               
     40102 Star Gazer-3                   Tents               
     40103 StarDome                       Tents
```

This is because the 'StarDome' Product has the highest prod_sell

My code returns the highest priced product type. However, there are 4 products within that type and I need to list all of the products within that type (which returned the highest sell price).

Can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include sample data and desired results.  But at a glance, you aren't filtering by product type, you are filtering by prod_sell.

Comment: It is crazy how sometimes just typing out a question helps to find the answer. I did a sub-query within the sub-query to filter it by the type, then the sell price.
Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you commented, query of a subquery of another subquery ... sounds quite inefficient, querying the same table all over again (3 times, I guess).

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * From products;

   PROD_NO PROD_NAME    PROD_  PROD_SELL
---------- ------------ ----- ----------
     40100 Star Lite    Tents        200
     40101 Star Gazer-2 Tents        100
     40102 Star Gazer-3 Tents        150
     40103 StarDome     Tents        500  --> the most expensive, so - you want all "Tents" as a result
     10000 Whatever     Beds         400
     10001 Something    Bikes        450

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

This is your current query (if I guessed right; table products is referenced 3 times):

```
SQL> select prod_no, prod_name, prod_type
  2  from products                                                 --> first
  3  where prod_type in (select prod_type
  4                      from products                             --> second
  5                      where prod_sell = (select max(prod_sell)
  6                                         from products          --> third
  7                                        )
  8                     )
  9  order by prod_no;

   PROD_NO PROD_NAME    PROD_
---------- ------------ -----
     40100 Star Lite    Tents
     40101 Star Gazer-2 Tents
     40102 Star Gazer-3 Tents
     40103 StarDome     Tents

SQL>
```

---

I'd suggest you to consider another approach: use analytic function to *rank* products by price, and then fetch those that ranked the *highest*.

```
SQL> select prod_type,
  2    max(prod_sell) max_prod_sell,
  3    rank() over (order by max(prod_sell) desc) rnk
  4  from products
  5  group by prod_type;

PROD_ MAX_PROD_SELL        RNK
----- ------------- ----------
Tents           500          1     --> Tents rank as "highest"
Bikes           450          2
Beds            400          3

SQL>
```

Now, use that query as a subquery (or a CTE, as I did):

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select prod_type,
  3            rank() over (order by max(prod_sell) desc) rnk
  4     from products                                             --> first
  5     group by prod_type
  6    )
  7  select p.prod_no, p.prod_name, p.prod_type
  8  from products p join temp t on t.prod_type = p.prod_type     --> second
  9  where t.rnk = 1
 10  order by p.prod_no;

   PROD_NO PROD_NAME    PROD_
---------- ------------ -----
     40100 Star Lite    Tents
     40101 Star Gazer-2 Tents
     40102 Star Gazer-3 Tents
     40103 StarDome     Tents

SQL>
```

That's the same result you got, but should be somewhat more efficient. Certainly, you won't notice any difference on small tables, but might as number of rows gets higher and higher.